# D3 force layout source code snippet !quad.leaf

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Does anyone know the reason for this random perturbation on line 5529 of the D3 source code?

```
  if (!quad.leaf) {
    quad.point.x += Math.random() - .5;
    quad.point.y += Math.random() - .5;
  }
```

Comment: As much as I want to help you, this question is EXTREMELY specific and is most likely going to get closed. Just taking a quick look I am wondering this also, but I think emailing the author or asking on d3.js group or irc is going to lead to a better result.

Comment: ok thanks I appreciate the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file d3.js concatenates several source code files. The lines that you are refering to are in the [force implementation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js). In this file, you can find the explanation of the perturbation:

```
// jitter internal nodes that are coincident
if (!quad.leaf) {
  quad.point.x += Math.random() - .5;
  quad.point.y += Math.random() - .5;
}
```

The random perturbation is there to handle coincident nodes. It's true that the question is very specific, but it's a good question in my opinion.